# How to use .each() of jQuery for more divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var selectedElmt=$("#sample1Div");
```

and I have to use the `selectedElmt` in a for loop

```
for(var val in publicationDatesList)
{

//my code

}
```

How can I apply this for loop for more selectors?

For example I am having some more selectors like `sample2Div`, `sample3Div`.

Comment: make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine selectors, you can either space-separate them in a single selector:

```
var group = $('#foo, #bar');
```

or you can use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to merge the contents of a new jQuery object into the previous object:

```
var group = $('#foo').add('#bar');
```

To loop over those, the easiest solution is `.each`:

```
group.each(function() {
   // "this" is now the required element
   // wrap with $(this) if you want to call jQuery functions on it
   ...
});
```

Comment: where to use .each here..?

Comment: @sasi wherever you want - the OP never said anything about looping over each element.

Comment: @Alnitak i had mentioned ..I have to use the selectedElmt in a for loop check in the question

Comment: @sakar I did wonder, except that the `for` loop you showed talks about a `publicationDatesList` which is completely unrelated to your elements.  You also said you wanted to use it _in_ the loop, rather than loop _over_ that set.

Answer (score 1):

select all (separate it with comma) and use `.each`, example:

```
$("#sample1Div, #sample2div, #sample3div").each(function(index, eachObject){
    // do something, example :
    alert($(eachObject).html());
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(eachObject)` you could write `$(this)`, and get rid of callback's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.each** function with multiple elements selector.

```
$("#sample1Div, #sample2Div, #sample3Div").each(function(i, k){
    // do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give to that div's the same class, for example: class="sampleDiv", you could do this:

```
$.each($(".sampleDiv"), function(index, element){

   //do what you want with each element

});
```